# Python, how to use csv module with selenium

Tags: python, csv, selenium

Anyone could help me here? Trying to export to a csv file (save it in C:\test\ with file name todays date) the data I am selecting with Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\python34\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'http://www.ssss.com/queries_pub.php'
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='query_choice']/option[text()='60 days']").click() 

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit\"]').click() # working to press submit
```

How could I integrate the code above with CSV module? Right now the chrome opens, enters in a page selecting a dropdown menu, and then in a new page there is a table with the xpath //*[@id="page1"]/table/tbody . Thank you.

html Table looks like this (just 2 entries in this case):

```
        </td><td>
            <input type='submit' value='Get Results'>
        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
        </form><div id="loader">
        <img src="img/load.gif">
    </div><div id = "page1" style="display:none;"><table class='maskAdmin' align='left'>
                    <tr><th width='200px' align='left'>NAME</th><th width='200px' align='left'>ACCESSDATE</th></tr><tr><td width='200px' align='left'>0011</td><td width='200px' align='left'>2015-07-29 00:00:00.000</td></tr><tr><td width='200px' align='left'>0002</td><td width='200px' align='left'>2015-11-23 00:00:00.000</td></tr></table><form action='queries_export.php' method='POST'>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>    
                <input type='submit' name='export' value='Export'>
                <input type='hidden' name='export_value' value='DEVICENAME;ACCESSDATE;
0011;2015-07-29 00:00:00.000;
0002;2015-11-23 00:00:00.000;

'>
        </td>
        </tr>
                </table>
        </form></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML code of the table and the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe , unfortunately I can't share  as it is an intranet page. Not sure if it helps but the XPATH of the table is //*[@id="page1"]/table/tbody . and it contains 2 columns and several rows. So the csv should be like that as well, a table with 2 columns and many rows where the first row as the headers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As long as I know the xpath won't be able to return a 2d arrangement, you will get a list at most. We need at least the structure of the HTML of the table with dummy data inside to be able to define an xpath and a way to reorganize the results into a list of tuples as an input for the CSV module.

Comment: @GermanRosales I updated the question with the html table. thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using pyquery (or lxml, beautfifulsoup, etc)

```
import csv
import pyquery as pq

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    html = #page source
    fieldnames = ['name', 'access_date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in pq(html)(".maskAdmin tr:gt(0)"):
        writer.writerow({'name': pq(row)("td").eq(0).text().encode("utf-8"), 'access_date': pq(row)("td").eq(1).text().encode("utf-8")})
```

Comment: I am using python 3.4.. so I don have pyquery module :/ Can you brielfy explain me how to do it with beautfifulsoup? thank you again.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to rewrite it right now. You just have to select .maskAdmin in beautifulsoup and loop through the rows, writing {name:first td, access_date: second td} to the csv DictWriter

Comment: if you could later help me out on this would be great.. Was reading some forums but didn't manage to do it with bsouo :/